# React mistakenly html escapes quotes in attribute names

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js / (SSR React) app. I am passing a property through props into a meta component. The tag that gets the string looks like this:

```js
 <meta property="og:description" content={ `${description}` } />
```

The content being put in there looks like this: `"This is a quote" - Quotes"` from a javascript string. The result looks like this: `&quot;This is a quote &quot;`. What I am looking for is the string that's passed into the meta tag, not escaped double quotes. What is going on here and how can I fix i?

PS: I tried using unicode chars, putting the description outside of a string literal, and something like `let q = String.chartocode(38)` then adding q in place of double quotes. All had the same result.

Comment: This is proper escaping, as `<meta property="og:description" content=""This is a quote" - Quotes" />` is not valid html since the double quotes need to be escaped.

Comment: further, opengraph does support html entities in attributes, so `&quot;This is a quote&quot; - Quotes` should be displayed as `"This is a quote" - Quotes` in the opengraph parsed view.

Comment: @shamsup Sweetness. Pretty simple oversight on my part. If you post this as an answer, I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proper escaping, since `<meta property="og:description" content=""This is a quote" - Quotes" />` is not valid html. The double quotes need to be escaped.

Further, OpenGraph does support html entities in attributes, so `&quot;This is a quote&quot; - Quotes` should be displayed as `"This is a quote" - Quotes` in the OpenGraph parsed view.

Comment: In some cases it doesn't for example in og:image attribute. You if pass url with &amp; it doesn't recognize it as proper image.

Comment: url attributes should be url-encoded rather than having the HTML entities escaped. For example:`/image.jpg?flag=1&another_property="this is a quote with a symbol &"` should be encoded as `/image.jpg?flag=1&another_property=%22this%20is%20a%20quote%20with%20a%20symbol%20%26%22`